# I get an error on getInstance() method even though i followed the osmdroid documentation correctly

Tags: android, osmdroid

getInstance() shows an error after following the doc correctly. but i need to know what version to be used here:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE):release@aar'
}
```

LINK https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#main-activity[image]

Any help?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention,  guide updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version in a way specified at the documentation [here](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/) :

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
```

You can always check which version is the latest [on github](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases).

Comment: 5.6.5 is the latest